# Help on previous question (Truthteller and Liar problem)

Tags: algorithms

There is a hint for part B, but I do not get which ones are the right cases to get rid of both goblins. Thanks!

[How can I tell who is a truth teller and who is a liar?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/17904/how-can-i-tell-who-is-a-truth-teller-and-who-is-a-liar)

Comment: It's only a hint. It's not a complete solution. Keep thinking. It's not an easy problem, but eventually you'll get it.

Comment: This should be a comment beneath the answer you don't get. (I realize that you have to earn some rep before you can comment.)